# Eloquent Javascript Chapter 4

Tags: javascript, eloquent

```
function hasEvent(event, entry) {
  return entry.events.indexOf(event) != -1;
}

function tableFor(event, journal) {
  var table = [0, 0, 0, 0];
  for (var i = 0; i < journal.length; i++) {
    var entry = journal[i], index = 0; // what is going on here?
    if (hasEvent(event, entry)) index += 1;
    if (entry.squirrel) index += 2;
    table[index] += 1;
  }
  return table;
}

console.log(tableFor("pizza", JOURNAL));
```

For the above code - What is the commented section doing? Journal is an array of objects, each with two properties, the first of which is 'events' and contains an array, the second is a boolean.  I can see that an object is being accessed and stored in entry for each loop through, but i don't know what the `, index=0;` is doing.

Comment: It's a [multiple `var` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The comma just allows multiple variables to be declared at once, without having multiple `var` statements.

```
var entry = journal[i], index = 0;
```

is equivalent to:

```
var entry = journal[i];
var index = 0;
```

Comment: Doh - I just saw that and immediately was thinking tuple, missed the obvious.